# Can I span groups of categories with horizontal lines in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data from six sites (reaches), as shown below. For analysis, I grouped some sites, indicated by the `pooled_sites` variable (i.e., Pools 4 and 8 were grouped (G1), Pools 16 and 26 were grouped (G2), La Grange (G3) and Open River (G4) were not grouped.

In the figure, I plotted the mean ± se of each site. I added the significance (`sig_pooled`; from the grouped analysis) above each mean.

I want to include horizontal lines that span the two pairs of grouped sites to indicate which sites were pooled for analysis. Thus, a horizontal line should span across Pools 4 and 8 (G1), and another line should span across Pools 16 and 26 (G2). Horizontal lines are not needed for the other two sites.

The `sig_pooled` codes should appear above all four groups. Where the two horizontal lines are present, I would like the significance code (A or B) centered on and slightly above the line. In the end, there should be just one A, centered over the line for Pools 4 and 8, and three Bs, with one centered over the line for Pools 16 and 26.

I figured I could use `geom_segment` like shown here, but I have not been able to figure how to specify `x` and `xend`. The code below just created four new categories.

```
geom_segment(aes(x = pooled_groups,
                   xend = pooled_groups,
                   y = max(avg + se),
                   yend = max(avg + se))
```

Can I do what I want?

**MWE**

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

reach <- c("Pool 4", "Pool 8", "Pool 16", "Pool 26", "LaGrange", "Open River")
n <- c(30, 6, 3, 29, 12, 76)
avg <- c(812, 819, 674, 649, 698, 679)
se <- c(24, 32, 43, 21, 31, 12)
sig_pooled <- c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B")
pooled_groups <- c("G1", "G1", "G2", "G2", "G3", "G4")

dat <- data.frame(reach, n, avg, se, sig_pooled, pooled_groups)

dat <- dat %>% 
  mutate(reach = factor(reach, levels = reach, ordered = TRUE))

ggplot(dat) +
  geom_point(aes(x = reach,
                 y = avg)) +
  geom_linerange(aes(x = reach, 
                     ymin = avg - se, 
                     ymax = avg + se)) +
  geom_text(aes(x = reach, 
                y = max(avg + se)), 
            label = sig_pooled,
            nudge_y = 20)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-12-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: This is less than ideal and doesn't include the horizontal segment, but might help get you started. Instead of the `geom_text`, try a `facet_grid` on both the group and significance code:  `facet_grid(. ~ pooled_groups + sig_pooled, scales = "free_x", space = "free_x")` Then adjust the theme such that the facet strips look more like plain labels.

Comment: I can post that as a larger solution if it doesn't deviate too far from what you originally set out to do. You could also take a look at how `ggpubr` makes similar [annotation bars](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/24-ggpubr-publication-ready-plots/76-add-p-values-and-significance-levels-to-ggplots/)

Comment: @camille The tip for `ggpubr` led me to [ggsignif](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggsignif/README.html), which works well. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to a comment above by @camille, I learned about [ggsignif](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggsignif/vignettes/intro.html), which is loaded by `ggpubr`. I added two `ggsignif` layers so I could set the line thickness (the `size` parameter) to zero for the two ungrouped sites.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggsignif)

reach <- c("Pool 4", "Pool 8", "Pool 16", "Pool 26", "LaGrange", "Open River")
n <- c(30, 6, 3, 29, 12, 76)
avg <- c(812, 819, 674, 649, 698, 679)
se <- c(24, 32, 43, 21, 31, 12)

dat <- data.frame(reach, n, avg, se)

dat <- dat %>% 
  mutate(reach = factor(reach, levels = reach, ordered = TRUE))

pos_nudge = 10
ggplot(dat, 
       aes(x = reach,
           y = avg)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_linerange(aes(x = reach, 
                     ymin = avg - se, 
                     ymax = avg + se)) +
  geom_signif(y_position = max(avg + se + pos_nudge),
              xmin = c(1, 3),
              xmax = c(2, 4),
              annotation = c("A", "B"),
              tip_length = 0) +
  geom_signif(y_position = max(avg + se + pos_nudge),
              xmin = c(5, 6),
              xmax = c(5, 6),
              annotation = c("B", "B"),
              tip_length = 0,
              size = 0)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-12-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>